# How do I download Chromium?

Tags: linux-mint

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

> epot_tools - this is our bootstrapped collection of utils that will help you checkout, compile, run and submit changes to the code
>
> src - a git repo; your local git copy of the chromium code. This will need to be updated regularly as other users submit changes.

Should I run these commands on git? And if yes, which one should I download? (http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)

(completely new to anything linux)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? I.e. what do you want to do with the downloaded Chromium?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too wide. You should rather ask for the specific things you don't understand in the howto to get the Chromium source code. But we can't explain how to use Linux, git, choose a git GUI, compilation and Chromium specific tools, in a single question... You probably need to learn the basics first.

Comment: Is there any place where I can learn the basics?

Answer (score 1):

Install chromium with the package manager of your Linux distro, in your case, for Linux Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```